# jQuery / bubbling - how to stop my javascript code for non-logged-in users?

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-bubbling

If you load my site and you have no `$_SESSION` (you are not logged in), I will send you this `<head>`:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/requires-signup.js"></script>
<script src="/js/core.js"></script>
```

My `core.js` file contains the whole site javascript code. For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.ajaxload-tab', function(){
   console.log('I shall do the load!');
   return false;
});
```

However, for non-logged users, this is preceded by the `requires-signup.js` file, which reads:

```
$(document).on('click', '.requires-signup', function(){
   console.log('No can do!');
   return false;
});
```

Now, I'm serving you this element:

```
<div class="ajaxload-tab requires-signup">CLICK</div>
```

You click on this element. Your console says: `I shall do the load!` Why?

**EDIT**

If I delete the `return false;` part in the `.ajaxload-tab` event bind, the code works as expected. However, I can't delete that part, because then it messes other stuff.

Comment: You realize this can be easily bypassed right?

Comment: I don't care. I have my ajax calls protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try using .off() in your requires-signup.js like so

in core.js:

```
$(document).on('click.requires-signup', '.ajaxload-tab', function(){
   console.log('I shall do the load!');
   return false;
});
```

in requires-signup.js

```
$(document).off(".requires-signup")
```

http://api.jquery.com/off/

edit: Or this method, if you don't mind globals

```
window.notSignedUp = false;

$(document).on('click.requires-signup', '.ajaxload-tab', function(){
   if (window.notSignedUp) return;
   console.log('I shall do the load!');
   return false;
});
```

then set window.notSignedUp = true in requires-signup.js

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the order of the files that you are loading in your head tag, something like this:

```
<script src="/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/core.js"></script>
<script src="/js/requires-signup.js"></script>
```

I think your problem is that you are first setting the "click" event to the element in order to console.log 'No can do!', and then, when you load the core.js, you override that "click" event with a new function.

Nevertheless, I recomend working with two separate elements, and display/hide them as you need.